# Different context menus on desktop in two Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit installations

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, dell, context-menu

I have two Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS 64-bit installations one on `Dell XPS L502X` and the other on `Dell Latitude E5440`. Although not exactly the same packages and themes are installed on both of the computers my question is that why do I not get the same context menu in both installations when I right-click the desktop? On `XPS` I have `Create Launcher...` as an entry which is missing in the context menu of `Latitude`. Do the tweak tools, dconf editors or something like that might have messed these menus? I do not even remember their default states. I am adding screenshots to illustrate my point and I am really curious how this might have happened. I would also like to have the context menus on both computers the same if possible.

The context menu on `Dell XPS L502X` is

[image: Context Menu]

Whereas the context menu from `Dell Latitude E5440` is

[image: Context Menu]

**P.S: Both screenshots are taken after right-clicking on the desktop with the application `Shutter`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the situation was caused by different versions of the file manager **Nemo** on the two separate computers. On `Latitude` I had a `PPA` which was activated and pointed to the latest release of **Nemo** together with Dropbox integration capabilities. However, I lacked that inXPS`so an older version of -version 1.8.4-1.1- was installed compared to the newer version in`Latitude` -version 2.4.4-2~webupd8~trusty0- was installed. After I deactived the PPA, purged **Nemo** then proceed on installing it again every context menu was the same on both computers.